# lazy quantifier on exact number of matches: "two times, but as few times as possible"?

Tags: regex

I am familiar with greedy and lazy quantifiers, but I was surprised to learn from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34806154/4885772) that there is a lazy equivalent for "exact number of matches":

```
+-------------------+-----------------+------------------------------+
| Greedy quantifier | Lazy quantifier |        Description           |
+-------------------+-----------------+------------------------------+
| {n}               | {n}?            | Quantifier: exactly n        |
+-------------------+-----------------+------------------------------+
```

How could `{n}` and `{n}?` be different? I looked up the description in [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions) and in their example for `{n}?` (which is different from their example for `{n}`), they explain:

```
[previous group]{2}?  Match the pattern in the first group two times,
                      but as few times as possible.
```

From my studies in mathematics, the smallest value of two that I am aware of is two. Am I missing something?

Comment: They are not different, `{n}` = `{n}?`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you; that's what I would have understood. I was confused because the answer I linked to, as well as the Microsoft documentation, suggest that they are different.